# Cbuilder XE3 scales (expands) form when edited in RAD IDE

Tags: dpi, delphi-xe3, c++builder-xe3

I have some applications, but not all, that "magically" scale up forms by a factor of 1.23 when I open the forms in the RAD IDE. For example, a form width of 947 pixels suddenly jumps to 1166 pixels. It is suspiciously-close to a pixel ratio of 120/96 (a ratio of 1.25), but the scaling is consistently closer to 1.23 (as judged by larger integer ratios derived from, for example, the form width and height).

I can look at the .dfm file and see the original numbers, whereas in the IDE, the values have been altered (e.g. height and width expanded, control positions adjusted, and font sizes increased).

I know that scaling and dpi is a minefield, but I've not (to my knowledge) changed any related settings.

For both the affect and non-affected projects, forms have the `Scaled` property set to "true" and the `PixelsPerInch` property is set to 96. My development machine has its screen resolution set to 100%. This is the setup that is supposed to avoid these issues.

I have searched through the project and IDE configuration files in a fruitless effort to find out what might be different about a project that has this issue, vs one that does not.

The affected (and unaffected) projects are all ones that have been in development for years - it is only in the last week that I have observed this behaviour. To my knowledge (I am sole developer), I have not made any code/configuration changes that relate to scaling, dpi, etc.

Does anyone have any idea what might be happening?

Although I am using CBuilder XE3, I've tagged this question with Delphi XE3 as well since I'm thinking that this is a RAD Studio issue.

EDIT 1: I've also noticed that for each modified control, the IDE throws in the following additional lines (i.e. in addition to modifying `Top`, `Left`, `Width`, `Height`, and `Font.Height`):

```
Margins.Left = 4
Margins.Top = 4
Margins.Right = 4
Margins.Bottom = 4
```

and for TImages, it also adds

```
ExplicitWidth = <nnn>
ExplicitHeight = <nnn>
```

EDIT 2: Curiously, when the IDE scales the form it does **not** flag the form as modified - i.e. the form appears unmodified until a "real" change is made (for example, repositioning a control). If the form is opened a second time after saving with the modified scale, no further scaling occurs - it seems to be a one-time effect, but there does not seem to be a "unasked-for-scaling-accomplished" flag in any configuration file :)

Comment: I edited the dfm file outside the IDE to add the Margins... assignments. When I opened the form, they got scaled up along with everything else (to a value of 5). Ditto for the Explicit... assignments. So, that was not the issue.

Comment: The issue seems to be related to a change in the value of TextHeight from 13 to 16 (the magic ratio of 1.23!). I am not sure what caused the change in value, since forms that had remained unmodified for years suddenly changed.